# How can I stop background from moving when zooming out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zooming

When the browser is at 100% the back images are great. Even at 50% zoom out they're still okay. but as you continue to zoom out all the way to 25% the background image position collapses or "hides" and I'd like the images' background-position: center top to remain intact no matter minimize or maximize.

I've attached an example:

http://i65.tinypic.com/k1e54z.jpg

You can also visit [www.medshopandbeyond.com](http://medshopandbeyond.com) and zoom out in your browser to see what's happening. [BTW: I am aware of the grammatical errors in the pics :) ]

The only one that gets close enough to what I want is background-size:contain
however the image is no longer full width from screen to screen if setting it to this

```css
#header-image4 {
  
    background-image:url("{{ 'old-friends-555527_19201.jpg' | asset_url }}"); 
    height: 750px;
    position: relative;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    margin-bottom: -50px;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -10px;
    
}
```

```html
<div id="header-image4"></div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you are using `background: cover` and a fixed height. As you zoom out your height remains the same but the width increases and `background: cover` will expand to fill that width which is why you are getting an unusual crop. The same issue can be seen if you pull out the width of the browser window on a large monitor.

Personally, I'd create a different height for the div at different breakpoints e.g.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1920px){
    #header-image4{height: 1000px}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 2560px){
    #header-image4{height: 1500px}
}
```

Comment: That is EXACTLY what is happening. Incredible! I noticed the problem on a larger screen monitor but haven't been able to find a solution. I just tried implementing what you suggested and I still get the same result. Unless I am doing something wrong which is highly possible.

Comment: Apologies, wasn't sure if that would work with the zoom but knew if would fix issues at breakpoints. try using em's instead of pixels for the media query as alluded to in this article https://css-tricks.com/zooming-squishes/

one gotcha would be that the changes take affect on page refresh when zooming

Comment: No need to apologize! I appreciate you taking time from your day to help me out! Let me try using em instead of px